# List modules loaded with the options provided while loading

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

The function `code:all_loaded().` lists modules but do not list the options provided while loading. How to list the options provided while loading the modules ?

**EDIT**

For example in the case of ejabberd, the options to be passed to the module while loading is set in the ejabberd.yml configuration file. How to get those options from the **ejabberd** debug console (ejabberdctl debug).

Comment: What options are you talking about for module load ? Could you please show the command you are using to load modules ?

Comment: @MickaëlRémond Added more explanation to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the compiler options etc., if that is what you mean, you can call `erlang:get_module_info(lists, compile)`.